# How to declare a variable in objective-c (iOS 7) to store a "cell" based "grid", where every cell has multiple atributes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m creating a grid based drawing editor for iOS 7 and I will be using the “canvas/screen” (UIView type) divided into multiple “cells”, each one with the following attributes:

image (object)

used character (String)

column (int)

line (int)

foregroundColor (int)

backgroundColor (int)

Example:

I will need something like this:

myGrid[0].image

myGrid[0].usedChar

myGrid[0].column

myGrid[0].line

myGrid[0].foregroundColor

myGrid[0].backgroundColor

I’ve managed to make the basic drawing work (image placement on the screen), but I need to keep track of everything the user draws, like in an mutable array representing the full canvas grid containing every cells and their respective attributes as mentioned above.

What would be the best datatype to store the canvas grid? NSDictionary? Array of Structs? Anything else? and the main question, how to declare it? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An mutable array of custom objects would be the best structure for the way you say you want to access the data. myGrid should be a mutable array, with each element being a custom object with the properties that you want -- image, usedChar, column, etc. You won't be able to access them with dot notation (e.g. myGrid[0].foregroundColor) unless you also subclass NSMutableArray so that objectAtIndexedSubscript: returns an object of your custom class rather than id. Instead, you would have to access them like so,

[myGrid[0] backgroundColor]